# document.getElementById('element_id') vs element_id?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Many years ago when I studied JavaScript, that I later almost did not use, I learned that I could use element id in place of its name. E.g.:

if we have code like this:

```
<button type="button" id="addButton">Add</button>
```

we can use the element two ways:

```
addButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  console.log('click');
});
```

or

```
document.getElementById('addButton').addEventListener('click', function(){
  console.log('click');
});
```

The former version looks more convenient to me, but I found that nobody uses it. Why? What's the difference?

Comment: This is a well posed question, but bobince and others address the issue in more full depth than would be produced in an answer here.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables ?

Comment: @Webbies, I did not find it, sorry. Thanks for pointing out.